# How can I write python code in a shell script such that it imports a module and runs a test on it?

Tags: python, bash, shell, scripting, operating-system

How can I run python code in a shell script that imports a python module and tests that specific module?

For example:
from _some_path_ import File_We_Want_To_Test

```
if(File_We_Want_To_Test.Function_We_Want_To_Test(a, b) == True):
   print("great!")
else:
   print("bad!")
```

Comment: You cannot do this in an OS shell. You must use python interpreter to execute python code.

Comment: Can you guide me how to do that in an answer then?

Comment: @fwubb just run "python" for an interactive python session. Also look at "ipython" for more features.

Comment: I updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Python in your shell like this:

```
python -c command
```

Where *command* is a small Python program (a quoted string).

Example:

```
python -c "import my_module; my_module.function()"
```

See the page [Command line and environment](https://docs.python.org/3.6/using/cmdline.html)